# Can $G$ be a union of some of$H$ copies?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a proper subgroup. Then we know that

$$G\neq \bigcup_{g\in G} H^g$$

I wonder whether this is possible

$$G= \bigcup_{\sigma \in Aut(G)} \sigma (H)$$

If there are such examples I want to also know facts about such groups.

**Note** One trivial observation is that if $G$ is such groups then $Out(G)\neq 1$

**Edit:** I know that elemantary abelian groups satisfies this. I am looking for nonabelian examples and known facts about such groups.

Comment: What about $C_{2}\oplus C_{2}$?

Comment: @James: Is $Z+Z$ finite ?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo.

Comment: @james: I forget to write, I know that elementar abelain groups satisfies this Sorry

Comment: I don't know about known general facts. But $G=Q_8=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ - a group of unit quaternions, and $H=\langle i\rangle$ works, because there is an outer automorphism $i\mapsto j\mapsto k\mapsto i$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: THank you for example.